# Uniqueness of complex topological $K$-theory as an $S$-algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, ring-spectra

This might be well-known or trivial, but I could not figure out how to fill in the details: For an $S$-algebra $K$ denote its associated multiplicative cohomology theory by $h^*_K$. Suppose that I have an isomorphism of multiplicative cohomology theories:
$$
h^*_{K}(X) \cong K^*(X)
$$
for *finite CW-complexes* $X$, where $K^*(X)$ denotes the complex periodic $K$-theory of $X$. In particular, this isomorphism has to respect the products on both sides. The paper "[$\Gamma$-cohomology of rings of numerical polynomials and $E_{\infty}$-structures on $K$-theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304473.pdf)" by Baker and Richter states that the $E_{\infty}$-structure on $K$-theory is unique.

> Can I use this result to show that there has to exist an equivalence of $S$-algebras between $K$ and the $S$-algebra $KU$, ie. can I "lift" the multiplicative isomorphism all the way to an isomorphism of $S$-algebras? If so, how do I start? Can I lift the multiplicative isomorphism to a map of homotopy ring spectra, which is then refined to an $E_{\infty}$-map by Baker and Richter?

Comment: Can I "snaith" it? Maybe I can...

Comment: I think the answer is yes. At least, you get a map of homotopy ring spectra from your morphism of multiplicative cohomology theories by Brown representability, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387107/multiplicative-brown-representability . Then if I'm understanding the Baker-Richter result correctly must be an E_infty ring iso?